# Can I use といいですね in this situation? "I hope you haven't fallen ill again"

Tags: word-choice

退院して以来、健康問題がなかったといいですね。

I hope you haven't had any problems since you got out of hospital.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really use this expression as it sounds weird. The most natural would be `退院してから、体の調子はいかがでしたか？` or `退院してから順調にご回復されていれば良いのですが` and then when you have information that they were ok, go `それは良かったです` or something.

`退院して以来、健康問題がなかったといいですね` sounds ungrammatical. `退院して以来健康問題がないといいなと思います` sounds weird because a) it sounds like the speaker was ill, and b) ないといいな would mean "I hope there won't be anything in the future", but 以来 implies talking about the past, so it doesn't go together. `退院して以来、健康に問題がなかったのであれば、良かったですね` would be grammatical but it doesn't work the way the english sentence work (casually expressing sympathy).

Answer (score 0):

No, first, なかったと is not a conditional clause. It's given by combination of present tense and と. Second, the form of ないといい**ですね** doesn't make really good sense here because the listener can not hope it together. The one who can hope is only you. So, how about 退院して以来健康問題がないといい**な**と思います or so?